# controllerAs method is not getting called when others are

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I' trying out firebase 3 with my Ionic app. (I just made one to mess with - so I figure i might as well do everything right from the beginning, such as using ControllerAs notation)

everything in the controller works fine. just the `logUserOut` method doesnt fire - at all! I'm at a loss.

controller:

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, DataService, AuthService) {
  var ctrl = this;
  ctrl.icons = [];

  //// SERVICE GETS
  ctrl.allIcons = DataService.icons();
  ctrl.pages = DataService.pages();
  ////

  //// FILTER INFORMATION
  ctrl.loadIcons = function() {
    console.log(ctrl.pages)
     for (icon in ctrl.allIcons) {
      var i = ctrl.allIcons[icon];
      // console.log(i)
      if(i.active){
        ctrl.icons.push(i);
      }
     }
  };
  ////


  //// ACTIONS
  ctrl.logUserOut = function(){
    console.log('this is not being called')
    // AuthService.logout();
  };
  ////
});
```

html:

```
<ion-modal-view>

<ion-pane >
<ion-content scroll="false" >
<section class = "modal-container">
    <div class="item modal-header">
        <button class="button button-left button-icon light ion-android-close" ng-click="ctrl.closeProfileModal()"></button>
        <div class="light text-center">
            <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="controller.closeProfileModal()">
            <img class="avatar-modal" src="img/mike.png">
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "row modal-profile-row">
        <div class = "col">
            <button class="button button-clear">
            <span class="title light">Personal Info</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class = "row modal-profile-row">
        <div class = "col">
            <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="ctrl.logUserOut()">
            <span class="title light">Sign Out</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</ion-content>
</ion-pane>
</ion-modal-view>
```

app.js:

```
.state('tab.dash', {
url: '/dash',
views: {
  'tab-dash': {
    templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
    controller: 'DashCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'ctrl'
  }
}
  })
```

**EDIT:**
**It turns out the problem was with Sublime Text : for some reason, there was a weird cache issue - I was editing the file but the changes weren't recognized. I'm Glad that I asked because now I am using 'controllerAs:' in the $stateProvider and not 'controller: someController as something'. Thank you all for your help!**

Comment: Where is your `closeProfileModal` method ?

Comment: ControllerAs is a good first step. Next step is to have DashCtrl as Component instead of Controller: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component. Then $ctrl.logUserOut() will work fine.

Comment: @Weedoze I left it out, because it is working.

Comment: @NielsSteenbeek specifying the controller as a component did not work. thank you though. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In your app.js change to:

```
.state('tab.dash', {
url: '/dash',
views: {
'tab-dash': {
  templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
  controller: 'DashCtrl',
  controllerAs: 'ctrl' // <-- here
}
}
 })
```

I'll explain a little more. In your controller you set a variable to 'this'. The name you use can be anything such as wowItsAVariable = this; however when you attach your controller you can use a completely different name such as controllerAs: 'wowSomeOtherName' and that is how you reference it in your html. The name doesn't matter and I would stay away from using names such as 'controller' as that doesn't tell anyone what controller you're trying to reference. Hope that helps.

Comment: This has the same result.

Comment: Sorry in your html change to: <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="ctrl.logUserOut()">

Comment: right, thank you. still the same result and the method fails to call.

Comment: thanks for the edit, I changed the "controllerAs: controller" to "ctrl" in app.js and in the html - and just that logout method is giving me trouble.

Comment: Your state appears to be set up in a way I'm not familiar with. Can you change to something like:
    $stateProvider
    .state('tab.dash', {
    templateUrl: 'someUrl',
    controller: 'someController',
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    url: 'url'
});

Comment: I am using `$stateProvider`

Comment: What I mean is what is 'views'?

Comment: that is pretty much what I have: the views:{} tell the app which tab is active when viewing the page.

Comment: the problem was with Sublime not actually editing the file...when i restarted the program the LogUserOut method wasnt even written in the controller. Thanks for your help.